# In VF page Action function not passing value to Controller

Tags: apex, actionfunction, selectcheckboxes

I've written a vf page and try to send value from `<apex:actionFunction>` vf page to controller but in controller, i think `searchjob()` function is not executing. and i'm not getting any debug statement in debug log.

In controller i've to take the value from vf page and add to list.

Please help

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" controller="Student_Controller">
<apex:form >
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSearch(a) 
        { 
              alert(a);
              UpdateUser(a);
        }  
   </script>

<apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:actionFunction name="UpdateUser" action="{!SearchJob}" reRender="" >
        <apex:param name="param1" value="" />
     </apex:actionFunction>

     <div id="category" style="">Category: <br/>
        <apex:selectcheckboxes layout="pagedirection" value="{!ProductName}" onclick="doSearch(this.value);" style="">                   
            <apex:selectoptions value="{!ProductNames}" />  
            <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" oncomplete="" reRender="" />
        </apex:selectcheckboxes> 
     </div>  

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controler;

```
public with sharing class Student_Controller {

public List<string> ProductName{get;set;}
public list<string> lst{get;set;}

public List<selectoption> getProductNames() 
{           
    list<selectoption> options = new list<selectoption>();            

    //Product Name is a MultiSelect Picklist               
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = student__c.Approval_Status__c.getDescribe();

    list<schema.picklistentry> values = fieldResult.getPickListValues();               
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : values) 
    {                  
    options.add(new SelectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue()));
    }           
    return options; 
}

 public PageReference SearchJob() {

     String SearchCompany = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1');
      system.debug('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'+SearchCompany );
      lst = new list<string>();
      lst.add(SearchCompany );
       system.debug('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'+lst);
     return null;
     }
 }
```

Please suggest what is the problem here;

Comment: never tried `rerender=""` so not sure this is issue but can you try `rerender="temp"`. Also you are getting alert?

Comment: @Tushar Sharma. I've tried it but, not working.

Comment: @TusharSharma `rerender=""` works just fine if you want to prevent a full page refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized you `String[] ProductNames`. The fact that it does not throw an error about being unable to set the value when using an action function could be considered a platform bug I guess. I got the error message when using the command button.

you can use the example below or add the constructor to your existing code and it will work. When passing the list of strings you need to initialize it before you can add to is via component. At least that is what I found. Simply adding the constructor produced the desired results. but using the onclick like you did with `this.value` and the param only passes the value of the clicked checkbox (regardless of state)

Also change your JS event from `onclick` to `onchange`

**Class**

```
public with sharing class Student_Controller {

public List<string> ProductName{get;set;}
public list<string> lst{get;set;}

public Student_Controller(){
    ProductName = New String[]{};
}

public List<selectoption> getProductNames() 
{           
    list<selectoption> options = new list<selectoption>{New SelectOption('','Select')};            

    //Product Name is a MultiSelect Picklist               
    options.add(new SelectOption('1', '1'));

    return options; 
}

 public PageReference SearchJob() {

     String SearchCompany = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1');
      system.debug('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'+SearchCompany );
      lst = new list<string>();
      lst.add(SearchCompany );
       system.debug('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'+lst);
     return null;
     }
 }
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" controller="Student_Controller">
<apex:form >
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSearch(a) 
        { 
              alert(a);
              UpdateUser(a);
        }  
   </script>

<apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:actionFunction name="UpdateUser" action="{!SearchJob}" reRender="" >
        <apex:param name="param1" value="" />
     </apex:actionFunction>

     <div id="category" style="">Category: <br/>
        <apex:selectcheckboxes layout="pagedirection" value="{!ProductName}" onchange="doSearch(this.value);" style="">                   
            <apex:selectoptions value="{!ProductNames}" />  
            <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" oncomplete="" reRender="" />
        </apex:selectcheckboxes> 
     </div>  

</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Since you are assigning the values to `ProductName` just use `ProductName` in your code instead of the param to ensure only the checked values are used

To ensure that only the selected Items are used use the standard functionality and use ProductName.

**Example Class**

```
public with sharing class Student_Controller {

public string[] ProductName {get;set;}

public Student_Controller(){
    ProductName = New String[]{};
}
public List<selectoption> getProductNames() 
{           
    list<selectoption> options = new list<selectoption>{New SelectOption('','Select')};            

    //Product Name is a MultiSelect Picklist               
    options.add(new SelectOption('1', '1'));

    return options; 
}



 public void SearchJob() {
      system.debug(ProductName);
     }
 }
```

**Example Page**

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" controller="Student_Controller">
<apex:form >
<apex:Messages id="msgs"/>
<apex:pageBlock >

     <div id="category" style="">Category: <br/>
        <apex:selectcheckboxes layout="pagedirection" value="{!ProductName}" >                   
            <apex:selectoptions value="{!ProductNames}" />  
        </apex:selectcheckboxes> 
     </div>  



</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandbutton action="{!SearchJob}" rerender="" value="click me"/>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

I would be remiss if I did not point you to the [Manual](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectCheckboxes.htm) which has excellent examples

Comment: As i've to pass value to controller by using actionfuction,i'm not getting . Can you please give me code.

Comment: @Amol - See updated answer

Comment: I dont want to use a button, as i 'm running it as a dynamic filter on vf page. Thats why i'm passinig value from action function by javascript.

Comment: Then don't use the dang button. Add the constructor to your class to initialize the String[] like I mentioned and it will work. But you will need to work on the value you pass because all you are passing is the option value of the checkbox regardless of if it is checked or not

Comment: @Amol - And change your event from on click to onchange

Comment: Thanx i've put in contructor it works, but as you said when we deselect  the checkbox i'm getting checkbox value. But, i want value should be null in controller when uncheck. and when i try to add value in the list, previous value get replaced with new value.

Comment: @Amol those are different questions. Please start a new question and close this one out. The last question is easy to spot if you look at your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49359/discussion-between-amol-and-eric).